# Create extension function (function with . in name)

Tags: kotlinpoet

I want to generate a very simply class that just contains extension functions, like e.g. following:

```
import com.my.app.SomeClass

fun SomeClass.function() {
}
```

**What I try:**

```
val packageName = ...
val annotatedClassName = annotatedElement.simpleName
val fileName = "${annotatedClassName}_KotArgsExtensions"

val extensionBuilder = FileSpec.builder(packageName, fileName)

val funSpecBuilder= FunSpec.builder("${SomeClass::class.java.simpleName}.function").build()
extensionBuilder.addImport(SomeClass::class.java.`package`.name, SomeClass::class.java.simpleName)

extensionBuilder.addFunction(funSpecBuilder)
```

**What I get:**

```
import com.my.app.SomeClass

fun `SomeClass.function`() {
}
```

**Question**

How I can I correctly create an extension function like `fun SomeClass.function()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`FunSpec.Builder.receiver()`](https://square.github.io/kotlinpoet/1.x/kotlinpoet/com.squareup.kotlinpoet/-fun-spec/-builder/receiver/):

```
val builder = FunSpec.builder("function")
    .receiver(SomeClass::class)
    .build()
println(builder.build().toString())
```

Will give you:

```
fun com.my.app.SomeClass.function() {
}
```